# GuzzleHttp firebase messaging INVALID_ARGUMENT The message is not set

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement a function to send a a notification using FirebaseCloudMessaging, I got the Auth part, But seems there is an issue with the GuzzleHttp\Client and how it passes the `data` part

This is my code

```
public function send(){
        putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path-to-json-file>.json');
        $scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'];

        $middleware = ApplicationDefaultCredentials::getMiddleware($scopes);
        $stack = HandlerStack::create();
        $stack->push($middleware);

        // create the HTTP client
        $client = new Client([
            'handler' => $stack,
            'base_uri' => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com',
            'auth' => 'google_auth'
        ]);

        $data = json_encode(
            [
                "message" => [
                    "topic" => "availableProviders",
                    "notification" => [
                        "title" => "New Order",
                        "body" => "New Order to accept",
                    ],
                    "data" => [
                        "service_id" => '1'
                    ],
                ],
                "validateOnly" => false,
            ],
        );

        $response = $client->post('/v1/projects/<Project-id>/messages:send', [
            [
                'json' => $data,
                'headers' => [
                    'accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                ],
            ]
        ]);
        dd($response);
    }
```

I keep getting that  response 400, INVALID_ARGUMENT "The message is not set."

`Client error:` POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects//messages:send`resulted in a`400 Bad Request `response: { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "The message is not set.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details (truncated...)`

Although my data structure is being passed as [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options), what I'm missing here?
Note: I use Laravel, I hided the , etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the Laravel wrapper

```
use Google\Auth\ApplicationDefaultCredentials;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

    public function send(){
        putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=D:\Projects\waterko_final\waterco-356810-firebase-adminsdk-brisz-11133a2abb.json');
        $scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'];

        $data = [
            "message" => [
                "topic" => "availableProviders",
                "notification" => [
                    "title" => "New Order",
                    "body" => "New Order to accept",
                ],
                "data" => [
                    "service_id" => '1'
                ],
            ],
            "validateOnly" => false,
        ];

        $headers = [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ];

        $middleware = ApplicationDefaultCredentials::getMiddleware($scopes);
        $stack = HandlerStack::create();
        $stack->push($middleware);

        $client = new Client([
            'handler' => $stack,
            'base_uri' => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com',
            'auth' => 'google_auth'
        ]);

        return Http::withHeaders($headers)->bodyFormat("json")->setClient($client)
            ->post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/waterco-356810/messages:send', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue, here's what worked for me:

`$data` should not be json encoded, but passed as an array.

And instead of the `json` key, it's safer to use the constant : `GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON`

```php
$data = [
    "message" => [
        "topic" => "availableProviders",
        "notification" => [
            "title" => "New Order",
            "body" => "New Order to accept",
        ],
        "data" => [
            "service_id" => '1'
        ],
    ],
    "validateOnly" => false,
];
$response = $client->post('/v1/projects/<Project-id>/messages:send', [
    [
        GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => $data,
        'headers' => [
            'accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I paste some code lines from Google Scripts.

The payload should look like this:

```
{"message":
  {"topic":"email_dan.alboteanu_softvision.com",
   "data":{"title":"New document: filename1","text":"Open: filename1","docId":"myId01"}}
}
```

and the post:

```
 var post = { 'method': 'post', 'headers': headers, 'payload': payloadJson }
```

the request:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/' + mProjecyId + '/messages:send', post)
```

The migration guide - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1